# Removing the theme from one ASP.NET page in a project

Tags: asp.net, themes, code-behind

We have a page that creates a printable version of the customer's bill. We are using themes via `<pages styleSheetTheme="CityDesign">`. This page is not using the Master page nor has any style sheet associated with it. I have added `<%@ Page Language="C#"  EnableTheming="false" Theme=""  %>` to the page and `protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e) { Page.Theme = String.Empty;}` to the code behind. The page still has the theme applied. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out I needed `StylesheetTheme=""` not `Theme=""`

Comment: I needed to use Theme, but this answer led me to the right place. It seems like one of the two will work

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I couldn't get anything to work in the markup, but this solution does work in the code-behind file (aspx.cs for example).

Just add this method to your code-behind file:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Theme = "";
}
```